# ios responsive design not working (too wide in portrait orientation)

Tags: ios, iphone, iframe, responsive-design, scaling

I am working on an quiz application and I am trying to make it responsive so that it looks good on all devices.  The application is an html5 application and is contained in an iframe and set to fill the entire iframe.  The native width of the application is 640px and the height is 880px (this is how I calculated the padding-bottom to be 137.5%).  It works great on computers and on Android devices but it does not work on iOS devices.   Everything I'm reading seems to suggest that I've done it correctly but on the iphone the application is too wide for the screen in portrait mode.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="iframeresponsive_mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Student Quizzes</title>

</head>

<body>
<!--comment:  this next section makes a container div for the page with a max width (defined by css)-->
<div class="pagecontainer">

    <div class="intrinsic-container"><!--comment: iframe div begins-->
         <iframe src="scrolling/index.html">
  Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames.
        </iframe>
    </div><!--comment: iframe div ends-->

    <div class="ad">    <!--comment: ad div starts-->
    This is an add div...
    </div><!--comment: ad div ends-->


</div><!--comment: pagecontainer div ends-->

</body>

</html>
```

and here is the CSS code:

```
body {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: black;
}

.intrinsic-container {
  position: relative;
  clear:both;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  /* to get padding-bottom divide the numbers of aspect ratio */
  padding-bottom: 137.5%;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 640px;


}

.intrinsic-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.ad{
  background-color:lime;
  height:80px;
  width:100%

}

/* comment: page formatting make a container to constrain width and center */
.pagecontainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 640px;
}
```

I have included (to my knowledge) the correct meta viewport tag.  Why does this work so well in Android but fails in iOS?

Comment: Does anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution was to add the following code to the canvas element on the page
style="width: 1px; min-width:100%"

I had seen this code on stack overflow before but it didn't work until I added the above css to the canvas.   I hope this helps someone with a similar problem.
Brett